# SQL Fastest way to compare two dates (non standard varchar format and datetime)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I have two "date" fields that I need to join on.

The first is a normal datetime in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

The second is a varchar(8) in the red-headed step child format `mmddyyyy`

Now this gets painful because there is no easy way to convert to the corresponding type.  There is a built-in format that is `yyyymmdd` but that doesn't match the varchar format.

There are two paths I can see:

```
declare @normal_date as datetime;
declare @hated_date as varchar(8);

set @normal_date='1974-11-01 00:00:00.000'
set @hated_date='11011974'

--cast to date time with string splits
select @normal_date
where CONVERT(datetime, RIGHT(@hated_date,4)+LEFT(@hated_date,2)+SUBSTRING(@hated_date,3,2))=@normal_date

--convert normal date to ackward format
select @normal_date
      where REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10),@normal_date,101), '/','')=@hated_date
```

Which is better?  Or is there a better way?

**Edited to show costs**

```
--Operator cost (39%)
CONVERT(datetime, RIGHT(@hated_date,4)+LEFT(@hated_date,2)+SUBSTRING(@hated_date,3,2))=@normal_date

--Operator cost (57%)
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10),@normal_date,101), '/','')=@hated_date

--Operator cost (46%)
cast(stuff(stuff(@hated_date, 3,0, '/'),6,0,'/') as datetime)=@normal_date

--Operator cost (47%)
RIGHT(@hated_date, 4) + LEFT(@hated_date, 4)=@normal_date
```

Comment: Operator cost from the execution plan is meaningless. You need to run each one a million or so times using `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and compare. I think you'll find that most of these are about the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is yyyymmdd no?

```
RIGHT(@hated_date, 4) + LEFT(@hated_date, 4)
```

So, your script becomes

```
declare @normal_date as datetime;
declare @hated_date as varchar(8);

set @normal_date='1974-11-01 00:00:00.000'
set @hated_date='11011974'

--SELECT @hated_date = RIGHT(@hated_date, 4) + LEFT(@hated_date, 4))

select 'hurrah' WHERE @normal_date = RIGHT(@hated_date, 4) + LEFT(@hated_date, 4)
```

Comment: @Denis Valeev: Did you test it over a table or just one line as above?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select cast(stuff(stuff('11011974', 3,0, '/'),6,0,'/') as datetime)
```

**Update**

[image]

Comment: You might want to add `set dateformat mdy` before you this query.

Comment: that works, but its the same performance as the others.  I will say that the "hated" format is the format that will have less records.

Comment: @Nix How do you measure performance of different methods? Run on production?

Comment: I am using explain plans.. and i am looking at both my script similar to the above, as well as the actual "production" query plans I have no doubt that there are some much needed indices on these tables.  I just want to minimize operational costs

Comment: @Nix SQL Server doesn't have Explain plans. It has Execution plans.

Comment: The execution plan is a very poor way to compare performance of this kind of thing. You need to `SET STATISTICS IO ON` or use Query Profiler to see actual CPU usage over a million rows each.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is this:

```
MONTH(@normal_date)*1000000 + DAY(@normal_date)*10000 + YEAR(@normal_date)
=
CAST(@hated_date AS INT)
```

one more thing: it is more precise to compare real execution costs than to rely on the optimizer's estimates.

Comment: Seems like your approach is the fastest according to my results. Which are somewhat biased of course and this needs to be proven on Nix's production server to be the final say.

Comment: I wouldn't say "more precise" since the execution plan costs are nearly meaningless in a case like this. I'd say "the only way".

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you either fix the column to be datetime or add a datetime column to the table and convert the data so that you only have to do this conversion once when the data is entered (and once of course for existing data) This could probaly even be a calculated column. This is NOT something you want to be doing in select statements. If necessary create a dateconversion table with every opossible date in both formates and join to it if the table can't be changed.

You might also want to check to make sure there are no invalid dates in there which is always a possibility with storing dates in a data type other than a datetime one.

Comment: `If necessary create a dateconversion table with every opossible date in both formates and join to it if the table can't be changed.` Are you sure that would be faster than a simple string manipulation thingy?

Comment: If it is indexed I would expect it to be faster, but you would have to test. It could depend on the number of records involved. Conversions are generally slow. But fixing the database structure is the best choice of all. It makes it easy to do the comparisons, it makes it impossibble to put in data that is not a date and it will make it easier to do other queries where you need to do data math as well.

Comment: Can't change the tables.  I would love to... not sure why you would go with a "varchar" date that is in a bad format.